# FB.Login opening in new window

Tags: javascript, facebook

I have this code

```
FB.login(function(response) {
   if (response.authResponse) {
     self.location.href='javascript:postToWall()';
   } else {
     window.top.location='https://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth?client_id=XXXXX&redirect_uri=XXXXX&state=5140df0126eae59fbc72ac733383bda3&canvas=1&fbconnect=0&scope=email+publish_stream';
   }
 }, {scope: 'email,publish_stream'});
```

it's working but opened in pop up, i need to open it in full window. How can i do ?

Answer (score 0):

You are looking at the wrong API calls. See [Facebook OAuth Dialog](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/oauth/). It is impossible to do it the way you are currently trying to.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
FB.getLoginStatus(function(response)
{
     if (response.status === 'connected') 
                 {
                     self.location.href='javascript:postToWall()';
                 } 
                 else 
                 {
                    window.location.href = 'https://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth?client_id=xxxx&redirect_uri=xxxx';    
                 }
         }, {scope: 'email,publish_stream',
             return_scopes: true
        });
```